# react native conditional rendering

Tags: if-statement, react-native, conditional-statements, render

I am trying to use an inline if statement to check if a piece of data exists and if it does to display it. this code is currently sitting in my render, return block.

the problem I am having is that using this, the content is no longer being rendered

```
{(() => {
              if (this.props.data.size) {
                <Text style={styles.headerLabel}>Sizes</Text>
                {(this.props.data.size||[]).map((section,i) => (
                  <AddToCartRow key={i} data={section} productName={this.props.data.name} value={Config.priceToPriceWithCurrency(section.price)} />
                ))}
              }
            })()}
```

Comment: You forgot to return the component

Comment: You might want to check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053237/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-create-components-in-react-native/42057846#42057846).

Comment: hi, this is already within a render and return block complete code is here https://gist.github.com/pmcguane/6462dad133543dc6d91f3645b3ec0bf5

Comment: @milkersarac this doesn't really help as this would cause the heading to be repeated over and over again

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
render(){
  return(
    <View>
      {this.state.error && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>}
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

There you go.

Comment: Oh sorry. I just clicked the *"Run code snippet"* button above and the result showed an error. But I think it's nothing to do with your code. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

This below code also check empty string.

```
render(){
  return(
    <View>
    {!!this.state.error && <Text>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: this is actually more accurate answer

Answer (score 2):

In general, conditional rendering in React Native is the same as in [React](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). But  be aware that in React Native we can render strings only inside the `Text` component. So, for example, if we will try to put a string inside a `View` it will throw an error.

## Inline if with logical `&&` operator.

```
<View>
  {!!error && <ErrorMessage />}
</View>
```

⚠️ Double negation `!!` operator is very important here (also we can use the `Boolean` function) because it ensures that the left part of the condition will be a boolean value.

Why it is important? Because logical “and” operator `&&` will return the right side of the condition if the left side is `truthy`, and will return the left side of the condition if the left side is `falsy`.

Imaging we have a component:

```
<View>
  {error && <ErrorMessage />}
</View>
```

If the `error` variable will be an `object` / `null` / `undefined` everything will work as expected. But if we will get an empty string for the error ( error = '' ) then our component will brake, because we can’t render strings inside a `View` component.

```
// error = ''
// {error && <something>} will return the error variable (which equals to '')
// and we will get:
<View>
  ''
</View>
// which will throw an error (can't render strings inside a View )
```

## Inline if-else with ternary `?` operator.

```
{error ? <ErrorMessage /> : <SuccessMessage />}
```

or

```
{error ? <ErrorMessage /> : null}
```

Here we can return `null` or `<></>` (React Fragment) depend on our component structure and return type.

## `if` statement

```
...

const Error = () => {
  if (!error) {
    return null
  }

  return <ErrorMessage />
}

return (
  <View>
    <Error />
  </View>
)
```

## Code example

Please use [this Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@vladimir_vovk/conditional-rendering) to see the full code and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this eslint Rules:

```
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error",

  ...otherRules,

  // Two rules below help us avoid this common point of confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53048037
  // The selectors are inspired by https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2073#issuecomment-844344470
  {
    selector:
      ":matches(JSXElement, JSXFragment) > JSXExpressionContainer > LogicalExpression[operator='&&']",
    message:
      "Please use `condition ? <Jsx /> : null`. Otherwise, there is a chance of rendering '0' instead of '' in some cases. Context: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53048037",
  },
  {
    selector:
      ":matches(JSXElement, JSXFragment) > JSXExpressionContainer > LogicalExpression[operator='||']",
    message:
      "Please use `value ?? fallbackValue`. Otherwise, there is a chance of rendering '0' instead of '' in some cases. Context: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53048037",
  },
],
```

Link: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2073#issuecomment-864168062