# React showing 0 instead of nothing with short-circuit (&&) conditional component

Tags: reactjs, components, short-circuiting

I have the following simple short-circuit statement that should show either a component or nothing:

`{profileTypesLoading && <GeneralLoader />}`

If the statement is false, it renders a `0` instead of nothing.

I have done a `console.log(profileTypesLoading)` just to see quickly what the status of the `profileTypesLoading` property is and it's either 1 or 0 as expected.  0 should be false... causing nothing to render.  Right?

Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Since your condition is falsy and so doesn't return the second argument (`<GeneralLoader />`), it will return `profileTypesLoading`, which is a number, so react will render it because React skips rendering for anything that is [`typeof` `boolean` or `undefined`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/95a313ec0b957f71798a69d8e83408f40e76765b/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js#L107-L110) and will render anything that is [`typeof` `string` or `number`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/95a313ec0b957f71798a69d8e83408f40e76765b/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactChildFiber.js#L461):

To make it safe, you can either use a ternary expression `{condition ? <Component /> : null}` or boolean cast your condition like `{!!condition && <Component />}`

Comment: I'll accept this once I'm allowed in 3 min... but thank you, that makes sense.  I'm surprised this is not in any of the explanations I've read on this method.  It's always just been written like I had written.  No casting.  Lesson learned!

Comment: You can also use the `Boolean` operator as well if `!!condition` confuses you.
Something like,  `{ Boolean(condition) && <Component /> }`

Comment: a react truth table: https://jsfiddle.net/milahu/k2z3wocm/5/

Answer (score 56):

*0* is a falsy value, so when it is evaluated by *&&*, it returns 0. However, *0* is renderable by React because it is a number:

```
// Renderable values
1 && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders <GeneralLoader />
"a string" && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders <GeneralLoader />
0 && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders '0'

// Non-renderable values
false && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders nothing
null && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders nothing
undefined && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders nothing
```

---

**TLDR**

This is because of how javascript itself process [*truthy* and *falsy* values][1]:

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered true when
>   encountered in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they
>   are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined,
>   and NaN).

When used with the *&&* operator, the returned value depends on the left value:

- If the left value is truthy, the right value is returned.
- If the left value is falsy, its value is returned.

Examples:

```
// Truthy values
1 && "hello" // => "hello"
"a string" && "hello" // => "hello"

// Falsy values
0 && "hello" // => 0
false && "hello" // => false
null && "hello" // => null
undefined && "hello" // => undefined
```

The same rules applies to JSX because it is [a syntax extension to JavaScript][2]. However, the issue is that **

The issue is that *0* is a falsy value, so when it is evaluated by *&&*, it returns 0. However, ***0* is renderable by React because it is a number**

```
// Renderable values
1 && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders <GeneralLoader />
"a string" && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders <GeneralLoader />
0 && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders 0

// Non-renderable values
false && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders nothing
null && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders nothing
undefined && <GeneralLoader /> // => Renders nothing
```

Comment: By far the best explanation.

Answer (score 21):

This would solve the problem:

```
{!!profileTypesLoading && <GeneralLoader />}
```

As it will convert 0 to false. The reason is when it's `0` the next condition doesn't get executed and it behaves like a number in JavaScript so double negation helps here.

Comment: You can also do `{profileTypesLoading > 0 && <GeneralLoader />}` as the [React docs says](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored)

Comment: But sometimes if your variable is Number, like coordinates, which is zero (0), then it will give false, which is unexpected thing.

Examples:

`/// This WILL render component.
const xAxis = 100;
{xAxis && <YourComponent />}

// This WILL NOT render component.
const xAxis = 0;
{xAxis && <YourComponent />}`

Answer (score 15):

You can use the double Bang (!!).  This returns the boolean true/false association of a value and will not render a 0.

```
{!!profileTypesLoading && <GeneralLoader/>}
```

Answer (score 11):

A more straightforward approach:

```
{Boolean(profileTypesLoading) && <GeneralLoader />}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this

```
{!!profileTypesLoading && <GeneralLoader />}
```

Answer (score 2):

React will skips rendering type [boolean, undefined, null], and will render [string, number, ...]

Answer (score 1):

You can draw an empty react fragment.

```
{profileTypesLoading ? <GeneralLoader /> : <></>}
```

Comment: Just return null.

Comment: That is not null that is fragment. Means no element

Comment: The purpose of using `<Fragment />` is wrapping children, so if you want to render nothing just return `null` or `false`

Answer (score 1):

From the updated React documentation:

> **Don’t put numbers on the left side of &&.**

> For example, a common mistake is to write code like `messageCount && <p>New messages</p>`. It’s easy to assume that it renders nothing when messageCount is 0, but it really renders the 0 itself!

> To fix it, make the left side a boolean: `messageCount > 0 && <p>New messages</p>`.

https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering#logical-and-operator-

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate a false condition at first, using a const with ternary is a easy way. Example:

On this case a simple button is shown if someCollecctionProperty is empty else, a button with some-options-menu will be shown (Material UI Example)

```
export default function MyComponent({ obj }) {

  const jsxResponse = !obj.someCollecctionProperty.length ? <Button>No Action</Button> 
    : 
    <>
      <Button 
        aria-label="more"
        aria-controls="long-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true" 
        variant="contained" 
        onClick={handleClick} 
        color={'primary'}>
          <ThumbUpAltOutlinedIcon/>OK
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="long-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        {obj.someCollecctionProperty.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option.id} onClick={handleClose}>
            <Avatar variant="square" alt={option.name} src={option.url}/>{option.configName}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Menu>
    </>;

  return (<div>{jsxResponse}</div>);
}
```

jsxResponse is the rendered component, `0` on view can be avoid with this

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
{ Boolean(profileTypesLoading) ? <GeneralLoader /> : <></> }
```

also solves the problem. Since I am a beginner I don't know if this has drawbacks or side effects.

Comment: It is more verbose than neccessary: You already have created a boolean value which will not be rendered when used like `{ Boolean(profileTypesLoading) && <GeneralLoader /> }`