# With && operator, React showing 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-rendering, optional-chaining

I am using the below statement to conditionally render a component.

`{data?.length && <RenderThisComp />}`

data - an array.

RenderThisComp - a component that needs to be rendered only if data array has any value.

If the length of `data` array is zero, it is showing zero, whereas it should display nothing.

Comment: `{data.length && <RenderThisComp/>}`

Comment: Optional chaining is a stage 4 proposal, you might want to enable those in your webpack config.

Comment: Personally, I would just use `(data || []).length && < ... >`.

Comment: Given your setup supports optional chaining, `{data?.length > 0 && <RenderThisComp />}` should work.

Comment: Optional chaining is not a problem here. I have enabled it from webpack config.

Thanks, everyone for replying. 

I got an answer from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048037/react-showing-0-instead-of-nothing-with-short-circuit-conditional-component