# React Js conditional rendering of html element not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am adding conditions to display a div element and condition has a variable which comes to be 0 and when it is 0 then 0 displays instead of not displaying anything.

using functional component:

```js
return (
  <div>
    {flag1 && flag2 &&  data1 && data1.length && data2 && data2.length &&  (
      <div className="answers-heading">Answers ({data2.length})</div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

In the above code, I expect if any of the variables are not true then it should simply not display div element but I am getting 0 in UI.
When all conditions true then it works fine.
I have created [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pwlsrh) to show how it is working in an unexpected manner.

Any help would be appreciated.

Already spent a whole day debugging but could not find the reason.

Comment: If `flag1` or `flag2` are of type `number`, it is expected. You should use `boolean` type for these if they are really flags with only 2 useful values.

Comment: @Valentin flag1 and flag2 are boolean. In demo, I kept them false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
return (
  <div>
    {flag1 && flag2 &&  data1 && data1.length && data2 && data2.length ?  (
      <div className="answers-heading">Answers ({data2.length})</div>
    ) : null}
  </div>
);
```

You should start using ternary instead of only && operator, you will end up with divs with 0 rendered inside. You get 0 because of `&&` operator check which is basically indicating that your condition is "falsey".

Btw, your condition looks fine, you should put that into a `const` too.

This might help you out too: [React showing 0 instead of nothing with short-circuit (&&) conditional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048037/react-showing-0-instead-of-nothing-with-short-circuit-conditional-component)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from the fact that `data1.length` or `data2.length` is equal to `0`. It makes your condition resolve to `0` because `true && 0 === 0`.

If you want to avoid this, you may change your code to:

```js
return (
  <div>
    {flag1 && flag2 && data1 && data1.length !== 0 && data2 && data2.length !== 0 && (
      <div className="answers-heading">Answers ({data2.length})</div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put !! Infront of all numeric values and it will be true if that number exists and is not 0