# Next js shows a 0 at the top for one second on load page content

Tags: javascript, next.js

in my nextjs app, when the page loads there is a 0 in the top left corner for a split second. In that page, I get some data from Sanity CMS with getStaticProps and return the content.. I notice that even if I return a empty fraction the 0 appears.

```
  return <>{Object?.keys(finalContent).length && <></>}</>;
```

If I return just the empty fraction without checking for

```
Object?.keys(finalContent).length &&
```

the 0 is gone

```
  return <></>;  // no 0 in the page
```

Anyone know how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React showing 0 instead of nothing with short-circuit (&&) conditional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048037/react-showing-0-instead-of-nothing-with-short-circuit-conditional-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume with `Object?.keys(finalContent).length` you want to ensure that the data was successfully fetched.

As a background, JS has short-circuit evaluation, meaning:

- `0 && 3` gets evaluated as 0
- `3 || 0` gets evaluated as 3
- Analogically, if `Object?.keys(finalContent).length` is 0, it would be equivalent the expression `0 && x` which gets evaluated as 0

And in React.js, the `0` is the only falsy value that **actually renders** (null, undefined, and "" do not get rendered)

Therefore, a `0` is rendered to your screen when the length of the data array is `0`.

The perhaps easiest solution would be turning the falsy length of `0` into an a boolean `false` and all other truthy lenghts >0 into `true` like that: `!!(Object?.keys(finalContent).length)`

Final solution:

```
    return <>{!!(Object?.keys(finalContent).length) && <></>}</>;
```

Now, if `Object?.keys(finalContent).length` is `0`, it gets turned into a `false`, which will not be rendered by React.